# How to create material-ui.js file?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I've followed the getting started guide and have the example running, but it seems to load all of the js components from the example lib folder as separate resources. How do I get it to build a single material-ui.js (or material-ui.min.js) file which I just reference from my html? Do I use npm, gulp, browserify, etc? If so, how? I am not at all familiar with the javascript build and packaging tools. I just want a single js file to include in my static resources, like react.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm install material-ui
npm install -g webpack
webpack node_modules/material-ui/lib/index.js material-ui.js
```

You're probably using babel to transform your inline jsx (ie. following the React tutorial), so you can use the es6 import syntax:

```
import React from 'react';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/lib/flat-button';
```

The whole script block is:

```
<script type="text/babel">      
    import React from 'react';
    import FlatButton from 'material-ui/lib/flat-button';


    const FlatButtonExampleSimple = () => (
      <div>
        <FlatButton label="Default" />
        <FlatButton label="Primary" primary={true} />
        <FlatButton label="Secondary" secondary={true} />
        <FlatButton label="Disabled" disabled={true} />
      </div>
    );      

    ReactDOM.render(
      <FlatButtonExampleSimple />,
      document.getElementById('content')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Sweet!. That does pretty much exactly what I want, thanks. Another noobish question, though: how do I reference the components from other js/jsx code on the same html page? e.g. with react I can say React.render(...); what is the equivalent for material-ui? I cannot figure this out from the generated material-ui.js file.

Comment: Looks like you're new to stackoverflow.  It's good to 'accept' the entry that answers your question.  You can always ask more questions.

Comment: Added new follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967027/how-do-i-get-webpack-built-material-ui-library-components-in-scope-in-browser

Answer (score 1):

you have to follow the guids

First go to example folder

```
cd <project folder>/material-ui/examples/browserify-gulp-example
```

Run this

```
npm install
```

It will install all required packages described in package.json

Then

```
npm start
```

It will run web server

And finally just run gulp

```
gulp
```

It will run all gulp tasks described here

*browserify-gulp-example/gulp/tasks*

In result you will come with file app.js in build folder

You can include it in your html as usually

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Now you can run http://localhost:3000 and check for result

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't the problem I'm trying to solve. The examples already build a single large app.js.

What I want is 3 js files: (1) react.js (2) material-ui.js (contains the material-ui components) (3) app.js (my application js, which uses the other 2 libs)

The idea is that I can modify and iterate my app.js, while the react and material-ui libs don't change.

Comment: In webpack, code-splitting looks like it does what I want: http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html