# How do I get webpack-built material-ui library components in-scope in browser?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

Following on from this question: [How to create material-ui.js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372449/how-to-create-material-ui-js-file)

I cannot work out how to use the material-ui components in my page script. The material-ui components are not in scope. I'm not using babel or any other compilation step; just loading the pre-built js files on my page and using the JSXTransformer.

e.g. my html is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <script src="static/js/react-with-addons.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/material-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <script src="static/js/app.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
        </div>
        <div>Some text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I built the react and material-ui libraries as per the referenced question e.g.

```
npm install material-ui
npm install -g webpack
webpack node_modules/material-ui/lib/index.js material-ui.js
```

and copied the generated js file to my static files folder.

This is my app.jsx:

```
React.render(
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <RaisedButton label="My Button"/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

I get this error in Chrome: `Uncaught ReferenceError: RaisedButton is not defined`

I would expect the material-ui components to be in scope, but it appears not. At the Chrome console I can type `window.` and see a list of names in scope. This includes React, but nothing that looks like material-ui.

Comment: This sounds familiar and another trick I'm not recalling is needed.  Does it work if you put everything into the HTML file?  FYI, JSXTransformer is/was part of the babel project.

Comment: No. If I inline the app.jsx script it gives exactly the same result, which is what I'd expect, because the material-ui objects are not in scope.

Comment: It seems the options I want are: `--output-library=MaterialUI --output-library-target=var`. But this just leaves me with a new error: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: RaisedButton.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.` The goog suggests this is often caused by returning multiple elements from render(), but I don't think that is the case here.