# Material-UI Webpack build - lib directory missing

Tags: node.js, webpack, material-ui

I was trying to build a single file from Material-UI using webpack using this SO answer:

[How to create material-ui.js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372449/how-to-create-material-ui-js-file?lq=1)

Following the lines:

```
npm install material-ui
npm install -g webpack
webpack node_modules/material-ui/lib/index.js material-ui.js
```

"node_modules/material-ui/**lib**" doesnt seem to exist, at least in the current version of MUI. I'd rather not use old versions of any libraries. Am I missing some new step?

Material-UI version: 0.15.0
Node version: 6.2.1
NPM version: 3.9.5

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about older versions but the newer version the index.js file is in the root of the folder.

So you want to use the command

webpack node_modules/material-ui/index.js material-ui.js